# xamarin forms: Calling phone and sending email (IOS, Android and UWP)

Tags: email, xamarin.forms, phone-call

Currently using following code for calling and email features, but it is only working in Android and not working in IOS. Also, I need these features in UWP.

For call:

```
string phoneno = "1234567890";
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("tel:" + phoneno));
```

For mail:

```
string email = "sreejithsree139@gmail.com";
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("mailto:" + email ));
```

Any package available for this?

Comment: You can use this plugin. "https://blog.xamarin.com/cross-platform-messaging-for-ios-android-and-windows/"

Comment: @SrustiThakkar Getting page not found error

Comment: Sorry, It was my paste mistake. https://blog.xamarin.com/cross-platform-messaging-for-ios-android-and-windows/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/) ([Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Essentials)) is available as a preview package and contains functionality to both [open the default mail app and attach information such as the recipients, subject and the body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.email?view=xamarin-essentials-android) as well as [open the phone dialer with a certain number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.phonedialer?view=xamarin-essentials-android).

There is also a [blog post](https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-essentials-cross-platform-apis-mobile-apps/) about Xamarin.Essentials available on blog.xamarin.com.

Edit: 
As for your mail issue, Xamarin.Essentials expects an array of strings as recipients so you are able to send mail to multiple people at once. Just pass a string array with one single value.

```
var recipients = new string[1] {"me@watercod.es"};
```

If you're using the overload that expects an EmailMessage instance, you are supposed to pass a List of string objects.
In that case, the following should work:

```
var recipients = new List<string> {"me@watercod.es"};
```

Comment: I solved the calling feature using this package, but for mail I didn't get solution

Comment: I updated the question with my findings in mail code.

Comment: I have edited my answer to also answer your question regarding your mail issue.

Comment: Currently I am trying like this: List<string> recipients = new List<string>();
                recipients.Add(email.Text);

Answer (score 1):

**Updating the complete code for calling and mailing features using Xamarin.Essentials, this might help others.**

**For call:**

```
   try
    {
        PhoneDialer.Open(number);
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException anEx)
    {
        // Number was null or white space
    }
    catch (FeatureNotSupportedException ex)
    {
        // Phone Dialer is not supported on this device.
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Other error has occurred.
    }
```

**For Mail:**

```
       List<string> recipients = new List<string>();
        string useremail = email.Text;
        recipients.Add(useremail);
                try
                {
                    var message = new EmailMessage
                    {
                        //Subject = subject,
                        //Body = body,
                        To = recipients
                        //Cc = ccRecipients,
                        //Bcc = bccRecipients
                    };
                    await Email.ComposeAsync(message);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>>"+ex);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello to **make a call in UWP**:

```
if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneCallManager"))
            {
                Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneCallManager.ShowPhoneCallUI("123", "name to call");
            }
```

**To send a Text:**

```
private async void ComposeSms(Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.Contact recipient,
    string messageBody,
    StorageFile attachmentFile,
    string mimeType)
{
    var chatMessage = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage();
    chatMessage.Body = messageBody;

    if (attachmentFile != null)
    {
        var stream = Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(attachmentFile);

        var attachment = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessageAttachment(
            mimeType,
            stream);

        chatMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
    }

    var phone = recipient.Phones.FirstOrDefault<Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPhone>();
    if (phone != null)
    {
        chatMessage.Recipients.Add(phone.Number);
    }
    await Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessageManager.ShowComposeSmsMessageAsync(chatMessage);
}
```

as found in Microsoft documentation here: [Compose SMS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/sending-an-sms-message)

==> **So you can make** (If not already done) **a shared service interface** in your Xamarin app, then the implementation with these codes in your UWP app...

---

**To send an email:**
To send an email in UWP, you can refer to the Microsoft documentation too:
[Send Email documentation (UWP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/sending-email)

---

**Using a plugin**

Else you can use a Xamarin plugin:

- documentation: [Xamarin cross messaging plugin](https://github.com/cjlotz/Xamarin.Plugins/blob/master/Messaging/README.md)
- Nuget: [Nuget plugin package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Messaging/)

Comment: I need to make call and email(No need to send a text). Currently calling and mail are working in android only. And how we can these two operations in IOS?

Comment: I updated the answer: to send mail in UWP, or for iOS/Android/UWP: use a plugin

Answer (score 0):

In our app, we are doing the phone calling with a DependencyService.

Therefore in our PCL, we have

```
public interface IPhoneCall
{
    void Call(string number);
}
```

On the iOS side, the following method does the calling:

```
public void Call(string number)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(number))
            return;
        var url = new NSUrl("tel:" + number);
        if (!UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url))
        {
            var av = new UIAlertView("Error",
                         "Your device does not support calls",
                         null,
                         Keys.Messages.BUTTON_OK,
                         null);
            av.Show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If don't want to wait for the [Xamarin essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/) that is still in pre-release as of today, you can use [this open source plugin](https://github.com/cjlotz/Xamarin.Plugins). It works on iOS, Android and UWP. There is a sample from the github documentation :

```
// Make Phone Call
var phoneDialer = CrossMessaging.Current.PhoneDialer;
if (phoneDialer.CanMakePhoneCall)
   phoneDialer.MakePhoneCall("+27219333000");

// Send Sms
var smsMessenger = CrossMessaging.Current.SmsMessenger;
if (smsMessenger.CanSendSms)
   smsMessenger.SendSms("+27213894839493", "Well hello there from Xam.Messaging.Plugin");

var emailMessenger = CrossMessaging.Current.EmailMessenger;
if (emailMessenger.CanSendEmail)
{
    // Send simple e-mail to single receiver without attachments, bcc, cc etc.
    emailMessenger.SendEmail("to.plugins@xamarin.com", "Xamarin Messaging Plugin", "Well hello there from Xam.Messaging.Plugin");

    // Alternatively use EmailBuilder fluent interface to construct more complex e-mail with multiple recipients, bcc, attachments etc.
    var email = new EmailMessageBuilder()
      .To("to.plugins@xamarin.com")
      .Cc("cc.plugins@xamarin.com")
      .Bcc(new[] { "bcc1.plugins@xamarin.com", "bcc2.plugins@xamarin.com" })
      .Subject("Xamarin Messaging Plugin")
      .Body("Well hello there from Xam.Messaging.Plugin")
      .Build();

    emailMessenger.SendEmail(email);
}
```